# Which version of g++ support -xintruments=datarace compiler option?

Tags: gcc, g++

Which version go g++/gcc support -xintruments=datarace @compiler option?

Comment: Did you make a typo in your question? Could you please re-read it and make 100% sure there's no typo? Are you 100% sure it's `-xintruments=datarace`? Why is `compiler` with a `@`?

Answer (score 0):

> Which version go g++/gcc support -xintruments=datarace @compiler option?

None, such option is invalid and not supported by any gcc version.  From [gcc documentation about overall options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options):

> -x language
>
> Specify explicitly the language for the following input files (rather than letting the compiler choose a default based on the file
> name suffix). This option applies to all following input files until
> the next -x option. Possible values for language are:
>
> ```
> c  c-header  cpp-output
> c++  c++-header  c++-system-header c++-user-header c++-cpp-output
> objective-c  objective-c-header  objective-c-cpp-output
> objective-c++ objective-c++-header objective-c++-cpp-output
> assembler  assembler-with-cpp
> ada
> d
> f77  f77-cpp-input f95  f95-cpp-input
> go
> ```
>
> -x none
>
> Turn off any specification of a language, so that subsequent files are handled according to their file name suffixes (as they are if -x
> has not been used at all).

`intruments=datarace` is not a valid language.